# AngularJS directive with require and 2 controllers

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to have a parent directive and a child directive, both with their own controller?

Something like:

```
.controller('ParentController', function () {
    var self = this;

    self.action = function () {
        console.log('parent action');
    }
})

.controller('TestSomethingController', function () {
    var self = this;

    self.something = function () {
        console.log('something');
    }
})

.directive('parent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'ParentController',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            controller.action();
        }
    }
})

.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'parent',
        controller: 'TestSomethingController',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            controller.something();
        }
    };
});
```

I tried to do this one codepen like this:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/bdygeP?editors=101

If I remove the require, it obviously works, but I would like to keep the require.
Does anyone know if that is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `require` multiple directives.  Have it require itself as well as `parent`.  With this syntax, the last parameter of `link` will be an array of the controllers of the given directives.

```
.directive('test', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['parent', 'test'],
        controller: 'TestSomethingController',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
            controllers[0].action();    // parent
            controllers[1].something(); // self
        }
    };
});
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvBEwR) is a forked, working version of your CodePen.